# JupyterLab classic UX not Vertex Ai

Tags: jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created Notebook

vm_image_family = "common-cpu-debian-11-py310"
and got Classic interface JupyterLab.
Apachaika_0-1688678537867.png

I saw a lot of guides and official docs with the Vertex Ai interface JupyterLab.
I rebuilt a lot of time Notebook aka VM and still a classic interface without GCS, memory usage and etc.
[Classic Jupyter Lab UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPZmW.png)

How I can set Vertex Ai interface JupyterLab?
[Vertex Ai Jupyter Lab UX](https://supertype.ai/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/jupyter_lab-1024x543.png)

I rebuilt a lot of time Notebook with Debian 10, 11 and the same results.